# Using the Pochhammer Symbol in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math, mupad

I've tried to use a script that evaluates the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) (rising factorial) in Matlab, but it fails to evaluate `pochhammer(x,n)` whenever `x` is a negative number even though the expression is valid when `x` is negative (Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica give answers for `Pochhammer(-3,2)`).

Can anyone help me get `pochhammer` working in Matlab for negative arguments?

Comment: If you want help fixing your code, you have to show the code that isn't working.  If you want someone to just hand you working code, you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you're referring to [this Pochhammer function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/pochhammer.html). Note that `pochhammer` (not capitalized) is part of [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html#mupad), which is a separate environment available with Matlab's [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html). You can access MuPAD by typing `mupad` in the Matlab command window.

If, however, like a normal Matlab user, you wish to use the `pochhammer` function from Matlab itself and program with it, you cannot run it from the regular command window or Editor in the normal fashion, as you discovered. Instead, you must use

```
evalin(symengine,'pochhammer(-3,2)')
```

or the more flexible

```
feval(symengine,'pochhammer',-3,2)
```

See [more here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html). These both return symbolic numbers as results and only work for scalar inputs. If you require double-precision output and have vector inputs (only works for the the second one, `n`) use

```
mfun('pochhammer',-3,-3:3)
```

This is equivalent to using MuPAD's [`map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/map.html) function, so you could also write:

```
feval(symengine,'map',sym(-3:3),'n->pochhammer(-3,n)')
```

However, if you're not working with symbolic math at all, there may be no reason to use this function instead of a fully double-precision solution. The [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) is defined simply as the ratio of two [`gamma`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gamma.html) functions and can be implemented efficiently as (`x` and `n` must be the same dimensions or scalar – additionally, neither `x` nor `x-n` can be an integer less than or equal to zero, where the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) is singular):

```
poch = @(x,n)gamma(x+n)./gamma(x);
```

If `n` and `x` are integers you should use `round` to ensure that the output is exactly integer. The only pitfall is that for sufficiently large values of `x` and/or `n` this naïve implementation will overflow to `Inf` (or `NaN`). In these cases you'll need to do something else such as use the symbolic version (which may or may not return `Inf` when cast back to double). For integer values of `n` (and scalar `n>=0`), something like the following can be used

```
poch = @(x,n)prod(bsxfun(@plus,x(:),0:n-1),2);
```

Note that even for integers this can be up 20 times slower than the `gamma` version.

Comment: The gamma function is singular at x = 0, -1, -2, ... so the ratio of the gamma function (while perfectly correct from a a mathematical point of view) is not advisable as a shorthand for the numerical computation of the Pochhammer symbol, unless x>0.

Comment: @StefanoM: Very good point. I thought that I had addressed this, but I hadn't. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The numerical command `pochhammer` for Matlab (not MuPAD) was introduced in matlab version R2014b.