# Symbolic notation for functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, syntax, symbolic-math

Is there a way to use actual symbols (like the square root symbol instead of writing "sqrt()" and integral and sum/product signs instead of "integrate", "sum", etc.) as in Mathematica?

Comment: To down voter: Why? I think this is a perfectly reasonable and interesting question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially, but not within the main part of Matlab.

If you use [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html) (type `mupad` in your Command Window), the engine behind much of the Symbolic Math toolbox, you can display/print results from calculations in your notebook with various [levels of formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/use-different-output-modes.html). However, it does not appear that one can display what one enters with such formatting. Like Mathematica, MuPAD does have a [graphical toolbar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/notebook-overview.html) interface for selecting various commonly used types of mathematical operations.

Matlab was originally developed as a programming environment for numerical calculations and programs, whereas Mathematica was developed primarily as a tool for mathematicians to perform symbolic math and typeset their equations in a virtual notebook.

*Aside:* Though the MuPAD environment is distinct, one can access all of it's fuctionallity from within Matlab. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html) for how to call MuPAD functions. Some examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136111/2278029), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241621/2278029), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002906/2278029).

Answer (score 1):

Nope - it's how MATLAB was written. As far as I am aware, Mathematica is the only tool that uses symbolic notation for actual code.

I think a problem with having symbols instead of code is that you now need a way of writing those symbols (a menu bar, a tablet input, etc.) that would make it extremely cumbersome for a user.

Comment: i see, that's too bad ... and no, you don't necessarily need any special way of writing them. You still type out the function name, it just gets converted to a symbol. Like you can type "esc"int"esc" and it will turn into an integral sign in Mathematica. It's shorter than typing "Integrate" and takes up less space, makes equations neater.

Comment: I'd guess that there are others, e.g., Maple. Even the Grapher app, though simple, that comes free with OS X supports this. See also [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor).

Comment: Whoa! Mathematica has handwriting recognition?! I gotta check that out now :D Nice list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is based on its diversity of toolbox, one of the toolbox support the symbolic notions you mention is the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/).

The Math Toolbox includes the MuPAD language. MuPAD is similar to Mathematica language, and here is a basic tutorial of [MuPAD tutorial](http://www.calvin.edu/~tmk5/research/mupad_tutorial.pdf)

In addition to Matlab, if you want Symbolic notation, IPython Notebook also use the actual Symbols. And it is faster, newer and easy to use.

Hope this will help you.